# Joi How to allow unknown property as long as the value is string

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi, yup

I'm trying to compare between joi or yup.
our front end client react use formik which also use yup.
right now we're developing the backend api side.

Is there anyway for joi or yup to do something like this

```
value = {
 'en' : 'teststes'
 'fr' : 'aaaaa'
 ...
}
```

I would like to validate that the value is string.
the property could just have 'en', or some other language support that I don't know of at the moment.

I also wonder if there's a way to do this synchronously. I know yup force me to do it async

Answer (score 0):

If `value` needs to a `string`  or an `object` (with shape `{en: "value", es : "value"}`) you could achieve this using

```
Joi.alternatives().try()
```

The complete code would look like below..

```
const joiSchema = Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.string(),
  Joi.object({
    en: Joi.string()
        .required(),

    es: Joi.string()
        .required(), 
}))

const input1 = "Hello";
const input2 = {en: "Hi", es: "Hola"};


const joiResponse1 = joiSchema.validate(input1);
const joiResponse2 = joiSchema.validate(input2);
console.log(joiResponse1);
console.log(joiResponse2);
```

If the value is an object with known keys,  let's say "en" and "es" and unknown keys whose value has to be string, you could use `Joi.pattern()`.

```
const joiSchema = Joi.object({
    en: Joi.string()
        .required(),

    es: Joi.string()
        .required(), 
}).pattern(Joi.string(), Joi.string())


const input = {en: "Hi", es: "Hola", ab: true};



const joiResponse = joiSchema.validate(input);
console.log(joiResponse);
```

**This is a synchronous call**. The return value of `joiSchema.validate` is an object that has the below structure.

```
{ error: undefined or validation errors if any,
  value: input value passed,
  then: [Function: then],
  catch: [Function: catch] 
}
```

You can check `joiResponse.error` for truthy or falsy to see if there are any validation errors.

I don't see a similar feature in Yup (Might be I'm wrong as I just skimmed through the doc pages). In my opinion, the best we can do is create a dynamic schema based on the object using `Yup.lazy()`

```
let yupSchema = yup.lazy(obj => {
  return yup.object(
    {
      ...Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key] = yup.string().required()
        return acc;
      }, {}), 
      en: yup.string().required(),
      es: yup.string().required()
    }
  );
});

//This should fail 
const input3 = { en: "12", es: "Hola", fr: 1.1 };
yupSchema.validate(input3, {strict: true});
```

As you said, this returns a promise. So you should handle success and failure using `then` and `catch` clauses of the returned promise.

But there is sync version for this as well, `yupSchema.validateSync`, 
which follows the same syntax as `yupSchema.validate`

As per documentation.

> Runs validatations synchronously if possible and returns the resulting
>   value, or throws a ValidationError

```
yupSchema.validateSync(input3, {strict: true})
```

Created a REPL for you to play around with different approach.
https://repl.it/@nithinthampi/UntriedImpracticalShoutcast

Hope this helps!

Relevant documentation links.

https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.7
https://github.com/jquense/yup#usage